# Serve specific "template" page at any URL that ends in its slug

Tags: wp-query, pages, url-rewriting, query-posts, template-redirect

Still new to WordPress, so please go easy on me.

**Goal:**

Prevent users of a specific role from viewing other custom post types made by users of same role.

**Intended solution:**

Modify the URL and redirect to a custom 403 page when the user ID doesn't match the post author. As such, if the person attempting to view *example.com/%taxonomy%/%private-post-slug%* would instead be redirected to *example.com/%taxonomy%/403*

**Current redirect code:**

```
​<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'private_posts_redirect');

function private_posts_redirect() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $post = get_post();
    $author = $post->post_author;
    if( get_post_type() == 'custom-post-type'){
        if(!$user->ID == $author || !$user->ID == 1){
           $intendedtarget = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
           $intendedtargetpath = parse_url( $intendedtarget, PHP_URL_PATH );
           $intendedtargetslug = pathinfo( $intendedtargetpath, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
           $redirectslug = '403';
           $redirecturl = str_replace( $intendedtargetslug, $redirectslug, $intendedtarget);
           wp_redirect($redirect_url);
           exit;
        }
    }
}
```

**Current issue:**

I've created a 403 page with '403' as the slug, I'm just not sure how to serve the content of that template page on any page that ends with that slug.

**Tentative solution:**

```
add_action('init' '403_page')

function 403_page(){
    if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'403')){
        DO_SOMETHING
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I know this only addresses the post author, I've already got the redirects for users that aren't of the role I'm looking to compartmentalize posts for. Additionally, I am using the  Advanced Post Queries plugin to only serve authors their posts, however that doesn't prevent them from viewing others posts by typing random numbers into the URL and getting to view sensitive RFQ, quote, and pricing info that's unique to that user.

Comment: When you say that "I've created a 403 page with '403' as the slug" do you mean you've created a Page in the admin panel? If so, could you use `get_permalink( 123 )` or `home_url( '403' )` to `wp_redirect()` to that page? Otherwise, you'll need to create an endpoint of that slug. Here's an article by [Metabox.io on creating an endpoint](https://metabox.io/how-to-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress/). Also see [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/).

Comment: Wish I could select a comment as an answer. This got everything working correctly. Thank you!